# How to convert a string containing 2 numbers to currency with powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, currency

I have text files that contain 2 numbers separated by a '+' sign.  Trying to figure out how to replace them with currency equivalent .
Example Strings:

> 20+2 would be converted to $0.20+$0.02 USD
>
> 1379+121 would be> $13.79+$1.21 USD
>
> 400+20 would be $4.00+$0.20 USD

and so on.

I have tried using a few angles but they do not work or provide odd results.
I tried to do it here by attempting to find by all patterns I think would come up .

```
.\Replace-FileString.ps1 "100+10" '$1.00+$0.10' $path1\*.txt -Overwrite
.\Replace-FileString.ps1 "1000+100" '$10.00+$1.00' $path1\*.txt -Overwrite
.\Replace-FileString.ps1 "300+30" '$3.00+$0.30' $path1\*.txt -Overwrite
.\Replace-FileString.ps1 "400+20" '$4.00+$0.20' $path1\*.txt -Overwrite
```

or this which just doesn't work.

```
Select-String -Path .\*txt -Pattern '[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?\+[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?' | ForEach-Object  {$_ -replace ", ", $"}  {$_ -replace "+", "+$"}
```

Comment: Check out the format operator (`-f`)

Comment: For an analysis of what went wrong, see answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I tried to do it here by attempting to find by all patterns I think would come up

Don't try this - we're humans, and we won't think of all edge cases and even if we did, the amount of code we needed to write (or generate) would be ridiculous.

---

We need a more general solution here, and regex might indeed be helpful with this.

The pattern you describe could be expressed as three distinct parts:

1. 1 or more consecutive digits
2. 1 plus sign (`+`)
3. 1 or more consecutive digits

With this in mind, let's start to simplifying the regex pattern to use:

```
\b\d+\+\d+\b
```

or, written out with explanations:

```
\b       # a word boundary
  \d+    # 1 or more digits
  \+     # 1 literal plus sign
  \d+    # 1 or more digits
\b       # a word boundary
```

Now, in order to transform an absolute value of cents into dollars, we'll need to capture the digits on either side of the `+`, so let's add capture groups:

```
\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b
```

Now, in order to do anything interesting with the captured groups, we can utilize the [`Regex.Replace()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) - it can take a scriptblock as its substitution argument:

```
$InputString  = '1000+10'
$RegexPattern = '\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b'
$Substitution = {
    param($Match)

    $Results = foreach($Amount in $Match.Groups[1,2].Value){
        $Dollars = [Math]::Floor(($Amount / 100))
        $Cents   = $Amount % 100
        '${0:0}.{1:00}' -f $Dollars,$Cents
    }
    return $Results -join '+'
}
```

In the scriptblock above, we expect the two capture groups (`$Match.Groups[1,2]`), calculate the amount of dollars and cents, and then finally use the `-f` string format operator to make sure that the cents value is always two digits wide.

To do the substitution, invoke the `Replace()` method:

```
[regex]::Replace($InputString,$RegexPattern,$Substitution)
```

And there you go!

Applying to to a bunch of files is as easy as:

```
$RegexPattern = '\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b'
$Substitution = {
    param($Match)

    $Results = foreach($Amount in $Match.Groups[1,2].Value){
        $Dollars = [Math]::Floor(($Amount / 100))
        $Cents   = $Amount % 100
        '${0:0}.{1:00}' -f $Dollars,$Cents
    }
    return $Results -join '+'
}

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $path *.txt){
    $Lines = Get-Content $file.FullName
    $Lines |ForEach-Object {
        [regex]::Replace($_, $RegexPattern, $Substitution)
    } |Set-Content $file.FullName
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly . Had never seen anything  on regex.replace but still learning some of this stuff. Also hadn't seen Return $results - join before either but looking it up now.  Thank you

Comment: @IsthisHoldem The syntax for `return` in powershell is basically `return [any pipeline or expression]`, so `return $stuff -join ''` is totally valid :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this output?

```
$20+$2 would be converted to $0.20+$0.02 USD

$1379+$121 would be> $13.79+$1.21 USD

$400+$20 would be $4.00+$0.20 USD
```

Then, you may try this command in `powershell`.

```
(gc test.txt) -replace '\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b','$$$1+$$$2' | sc test.txt
```

- `gc , sc` : alias for `get-content, set-content` commands respectively
- `\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b` : match the target string (`numbers+numbers`) and capturing numbers to `$1`, `$2` in order
- `$$` : `$` must be escaped to indicate `literal $` `dollor character` (what you want to place in front of `numbers`)
- `$1, $2` : `back-reference` to the captured value
- `test.txt` : contains your sample text

Of course, this is applicable for multiple files like follows

```
gci '*.txt' -recurse | foreach-object{(gc $_ ) '\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b','$$$1+$$$2' | sc $_  }
```

- `gci` : alias for `get-childitem` command. In default, it returns list in the present directory. If you want to change the directory, then must use `-path` option and `-include` option.
- `-recurse` option : enables to search `sub-directory`

**Edited**

If you want `capturing & dividing values & replacing` old value with new one like follows

```
$0.2+$0.02 would be converted to $0.20+$0.02 USD

$13.79+$1.21 would be> $13.79+$1.21 USD

$4+$0.2 would be $4.00+$0.20 USD
```

then, you may try this.

```
gci *.txt -recurse | % {(gc $_) | % { $_ -match "\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b" > $null; $num1=[int]$matches[1]/100; $num2=[int]$matches[2]/100; $dol='$$'; $_ -replace "\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b","$dol$num1+$dol$num2"}|sc $_}
```

This command search files in the present directory and sub-directory. If you don't want to search in sub-directory, then remove `-recurse` option. And if you want another path, then use `-path` option and `-include` option like follows.

```
gci -path "your_path" -include *.txt | % {(gc $_) ...
```

Comment: Trying this now

Comment: updated this to    gci -path $path1\*.txt | foreach-object{(gc $_ ) -replace '\b(\d+)\+(\d+)\b','$$$1+$$$2' | sc $_  }  .  this works very well but does not insert a decimal.  Possible to divide output by 100 ?  I will give it a shot

Comment: I just now added the part of capturing & dividing & replacing. Please try it again. thank you:-)

Comment: First suggestion only puts a $ in front of the values, omitting the decimal point and 'USD' (as commented by I-Script-Alot). Second suggestion provides correct output only if value has last digit of 1-9 (not a multiple of 10c) and doesn't even include decimal point if value is whole dollars (400+20 produces $4+$0.2 instead of $4.00+$0.20). Further, `-match` only sets `$Matches` to the first match on the line but `-replace` will substitute those values into every match on the line. Also, use of `$dol` is unnecessary. A literal $ can be included by quoting it with \` e.g. "\`$\`$\`$1".

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression work too

```
\b\d{3,4}(?=\+)|\d{2,3}(?=\")
```

https://regex101.com/

Comment: The regex above matches the examples given and would separate the individual parts (in 2 passes with a global flag) but doesn't consider the possibility of the data varying outside the limited ranges in the examples. Further, there is no description of what to do with the matched strings in order to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions seem excessively complicated, first turning the string to values and then back to strings. Looking at the examples, it is just chopping up a string and re-assembling it while ensuring that the different parts (dollars and cents) have the correct lengths:

```
('20+2','1379+121','400+20') -replace
        '(\d+)\+(\d+)','00$1+00$2' -replace
        '0*(\d+)(\d\d)\+0*(\d+)(\d\d)','$$$1.$2+$$$3.$4 USD'

$0.20+$0.02 USD
$13.79+$1.21 USD
$4.00+$0.20 USD
```

Explanation:

1. Substitute all the + separated cent values with 0 padded values so there is a minimum of three digits, i.e. at least one digit in the dollars and exactly 2 for the cents.
2. Collect the individual dollars and cents for each value into distinct capture groups while simultaneously discarding any extraneous leading zeroes.
3. Re-substitute the (just padded) strings with the appropriately formatted versions.

It is interesting to note how the second substitution relies on the greedy nature of `*`. The `0*` will match just as many leading zeroes as will still leave enough for the remainder of the pattern.

You can put in the word boundary anchor (\b), at one or both ends of the patterns, if you have parts of a line where there are digits separated by + which are directly adjacent to other text and you want *them* to be **NOT** processed, otherwise it is unnecessary.

Note: the example above shows an array of `String` as input and producing an array of `String` (each element displayed on a separate line). When `-Replace` is applied to an array, it enumerates the array, applies the replace to each element and collects each (possibly replaced) element into a result array. The output of `Get-Content` is an array of `String` (enumerated by PowerShell when supplying a pipeline). Similarly, the 'input' to Set-Content is an array of `String` (possibly converted from a general `Object[]` and/or collected from pipeline input). Thus, to convert a file just use:

```
(gc somefile) -replace ... -replace ... | sc newfile

# or even

sc newfile ((gc somefile) -replace ... -replace ...)

# Set-Content [-Path] String[] [-Value] Object[]
```

In the above, *newfile* and *somefile* can be the same due to a nice feature of `Set-Content` whereby it does not even open/create its output file(s) until it has something to write. Thus,

```
@() | sc existingfile
```

does not destroy *existingfile*. Note, however, that

```
sc existingfile @()
```

does destroy *existingfile*. This is because the first example sends nothing to `Set-Content` while the second example gives `Set-Content` something (an empty array). Since the output from `Get-Content` is collected into an (anonymous) array before `-Replace` is applied, there is no conflict between `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` over accessing the same file. The functionally equivalent version

```
gc somefile | foreach { $_ -replace ... -replace ... } | sc newfile
```

does not work if *newfile* is *somefile* since `Set-Content` receives each (possibly substituted) line from `Get-Content` before the next one is read meaning `Set-Content` can't open the file because `Get-Content` still has it open.

Answer (score 0):

This is a separate answer because it doesn't explain how to achieve the desired result (already did that) but explains why the listed attempts do not work (an educational motive).

If you're using `Replace-FileString.ps1` from GitHub then not only are the examples not a general solution, it won't work as listed above because `Replace-FileString.ps1` uses the `Replace` method of a `[regex]` object so "400+20" matches "40" then 1 or more "0" then "20". Similarly for other attempts. Note, no "+" is matched in the patterns so all fail (unless you have lines like "40020+125" which matches on the 40020). Just as well, the replacement includes the capture group specifier "$0" (as part of '$1.00+$0.10') and other specifiers. There are no capture groups specified in the pattern so all the group specifiers would be taken literally, except "$0" being the entire match (if found). Thus, "40020+125" would be replaced by substituting '$4.00+$0.20' giving "$4.00+40020.20" ($4='$4' and $0='40020'). Probably, no matches are found. Result -> files not changed. (Phew!)

As for the `Select-String` attempt, `Select-String` would probably have matched the required data since the pattern matched up to 5 digits on either side of a +. This would send the matching lines (and ignored the rest, if any) into the `ForEach-Object` as `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` objects (not strings). (Aside: this is a common mistake by a lot of PowerShell, um, novices. They assume that what they see on the screen is the same as what is churning about inside PowerShell. This is far from the truth and probably leads to most of the confusion amongst new users. PowerShell processes entire objects and typically displays only a summary of the most useful bits.) Anyway, I am unsure what the `ForEach-Object` is trying to achieve, not least due to the apparent typo. There is at least one " missing in the first script block and possibly a comma also. The best I can interpret it is

```
{ $_ -replace ", ",", $" }
```

i.e. change every ", " into ", $". This assumes that the strings to be substituted are all preceded by ", ". Note: lone $ is not an error because it cannot be interpreted as a variable substitution (no following name or {) or capture reference (no following group specifier [0-9`+'_&]). The next script block is clearer, change every "+" into "+$". Unfortunately, again, the first string is interpreted as a regular expression and, unlike the lone $, a lone + here **is** an error. It needs to be escaped with \. However, even with these errors corrected, there are two big problems:

1. The default output from `Select-String` is a collection of `[MatchInfo]` objects which when (implicitly) converted to `String` for use as the LHS of `-replace` include the file name and line number, thereby corrupting the lines from the file. To use just the line itself, specify `$_.Line`.
2. A completely incorrect usage of the scriptblock parameters to `ForEach-Object`. While it would seem that the intent was to perform two replace operations, placing them in individual scriptblocks is an error. Even if it worked, it would output 2 separate partial replacements instead of one completed replacement since `$_` is not updated between the two expressions. (`$_` is writable!)

`ForEach-Object` has 3 basic scriptblock groups, 1 `-Begin` block, 1 `-End` block and all the rest collectively as the `-Process` blocks. (The `-Parallel` block is not relevant here.) The documentation mentions a group called `-RemainingScripts` but this is actually just an implementation construct to allow the `-Process` scriptblocks to be specified as individual parameters rather than collected into an array (similar to parameter arrays in C# and VB). I suspect this was done so that users could simply drop the parameter names (-Begin, -Process and -End) and treat the scriptblocks as if they were positional parameters even though, strictly speaking, only `-Process` is positional and expects an array of scriptblocks (i.e. separated by commas). The introduction of `-RemainingScripts` in PS3.0 (with attribute `ValueFromRemainingArguments` so it behaves like a parameter array) was probably done to tidy up what might have been a nasty kludge to get the user friendly behaviour prior to PS3.0. Or maybe it was just formalising what was already going on.

Anyway, back on topic. By specifying multiple scriptblocks, the first is treated as `-Begin` and, if there are more than 2, the last is treated as `-End`. Thus, for two scriptblocks, the first is `-Begin` and the other is `-Process`. Therefore, even if the first scriptblock were syntactically correct, it would only run once and then still do nothing since `$_` is not assigned (=`$null`) in `-Begin`. The correct way would be to place both replacements, joined into a single expression, in one scriptblock:

```
{ $_.Line -replace ", ",", $" -replace "\+","+$" }
```

Of course, this is just describing how to get it to "work". It is not the correct solution to the problem in the original post (see other answer).